# How to use dynamic dispatch in Rust for trait with generics?

Tags: rust

I'm using a trait called `RtspClient` so I can create different `Stream` objects with different rtsp clients:

```
pub trait RtspClient {
    fn url(&self) -> Option<String>;
    fn username(&self) -> Option<String>;
    fn password(&self) -> Option<String>;
    fn connect(&self) -> Result<(), RtspClientError>;
    fn disconnect(&self) -> Result<(), RtspClientError>;
    fn set_on_produce<F: Fn(EncodedPacket)>(&self, f: F);
}
```

then I'm using it like this:

```
struct Stream {
    pub rtsp_client: Arc<Mutex<dyn RtspClient>>,
}
```

but I get the error that `RtspClient` cannot be used as an object because `set_on_produce` has generic types.

How can I use dynamic dispatch for `rtsp_client` and still be able to set closure callbacks with `set_on_produce`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the function's signature to accept:

- A reference to a `dyn`, `&dyn Fn(EncodedPacket)`,
- A boxed `dyn`, `Box<dyn Fn(EncodedPacket)>`, useful for storing instead of (or in addition to) using immediately
- A function pointer `fn(EncodedPacket)`, which does not allow keeping track of state

See [Advanced Functions and Closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html).

You can also move the method to a different trait, and even have the other trait automatically implement the trait usable with dyn.

[Playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d574423fe685112c422dfcf27e87cbf2)